# "generation heat", "generating heat", "generated heat", which is more suitable to describe heat to be generated?

Tags: participles

> My new PC generates less heat than my old one.

I would like to rewrite this example such that heat is the subject. Could you advise on which of the followings is best?

> 1. The generation heat of my new PC is less than that of my old one.
> 2. The generating heat of my new PC is less than that of my old one.
> 3. The generated heat of my new PC is less than that of my old one.

Comment: The only grammatically correct one is #3, but it's not idiomatic at all.  *Generation heat* means "heat, of the type 'generation'", which doesn't make sense.  *Generating heat* means "heat, of the type 'generating'".  That doesn't make sense either.  *Generated heat* means "heat which is generated", which is correct in meaning, but it sounds very stilted.  Catija's examples of phrasing sound much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above. If you really want to make "heat" your subject, do that. Put it first.

The standard way of phrasing this would be:

> The [amount of] heat generated by my new PC is less than that of my old one.
>   The amount of heat my new PC generates is less than that of my old one.

Another option that's slightly more similar to yours is:

> The generation of heat by my new PC is less than my old one.

But this is a bit odd and I wouldn't generally recommend it.

Comment: Hi Catija. Just as you used "that" after "than" for comparison to occur between two noun phrases, don't you feel there's something missing after "than" in your third sentence above?

Comment: @Gustavson Not really. It's a different structure. I don't know why but it doesn't need it.

Comment: Thank you. Lambie also used it in a comment above: "The heat generated by my PC is less than my old one." It must be a special case of ellipsis in which the agent is introduced without "than that by..."